# How to prove that $f(x,y)=\ln{(y-x^2)}$ has no limit at $y=x^2$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I try to find a way to prove that $f(x,y)=\ln{(y-x^2)}$ has no limit at $y=x^2$ (it's border).

Can you direct me and give my ways to show it??

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when $y$ is less than $x^2$?

Comment: @Henry, there is no solution... But how does it's helps me? I need to use $lim$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some fixed $x$: $$y \to x^2 \implies z \equiv y-x^2 \to 0$$
So: $$\lim_{y \to x^{2^{+}}} \ln({y-x^2}) = \lim_{z \to 0^{+}} \ln({z}) = - \infty$$
The left sided limit doesn't exist because $\ln$ is simply not defined for non-positive numbers.

Comment: And why it's means that there is no limit?

Comment: Do you mean that: $y\to x^{2-}$ not exist?

Comment: Well, right sided limit doesn't exist in the restricted sense ($\to \infty$ is awkward, so It's called a limit in the broad sense). Left sided limit does not exist, not even in the broad sense, because the expression is not defined for non positive numbers.

Comment: But this is what I wrote? $y\to x^{2-}$?

Comment: @Yoar yes, that's how you denote left sided limit.

Answer (score 1):

are you asking for the limit $\lim_{y \to x^2} \ln (y-x^2)$?  if so, an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof should get you the contradiction you need.  (i.e., show that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, when $|y-x^2| < \delta$, $|f(x,y)-f(x,x^2)| \geq \epsilon$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;A:=(a,a^2)\;$ be any point of $\;y=x^2\;$ (for simplicity, $\;a\neq0\;$. You can later do this particular case by yourself), and let us choose the following line

$$y=ax\;,\;\;\text{so that}\;\;\lim_{x\to a^+} (x,ax)=(a,a^2)\;,\;\;\text{then}$$

$$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x,ax)=\lim_{x\to a^+}\log(ax-x^2)=\lim_{x\to a^+}\left(\log x+\log(a-x)\right)$$

But as the first limit on the right exists *finitely* whereas the second one doesn't, the left hand limit doesn't exist finitely either, and this shows the  wanted limit cannot exist (why?).